# Selenium Webdriver Duplicating ExcelSheet

Tags: excel, selenium

I tried to copy an excel sheet containing 7 colomns named Excel.xls sheet into ExcelCopy.xls , but Getting an Java Null Exception error at @After Test and  as am very new to this selenium coding please help me  !!

```
 package TestNG;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class DuplicateExcelSheet {
    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;

    Workbook w;
    Sheet s;
    FileInputStream fi;
    FileOutputStream fo;
    WritableWorkbook ww;
    WritableSheet ws;
  @Test
  public void f() throws Exception{
    int colCount=s.getColumns();
    System.out.println(colCount);
    ww=Workbook.createWorkbook(fo, w);
    ws=ww.createSheet("Data", 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) 
    {
    String s1=s.getCell(i, 0).getContents();
     Label l=new Label(i,0,s1);
     ws.addCell(l);
    }
     }

  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() throws Exception{

      fi=new FileInputStream("E:\\selenium\\Excel.xls");
        w=Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
        s=w.getSheet(0);
          fo=new FileOutputStream("E:\\selenium\\ExcelCopy.xls");
      }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() throws Exception{
       ww.write();
       w.close();
      fi.close();
      fo.close();


  }

}
```

Comment: What line is the NullPointerException occuring on?

Comment: @AfterTest afterTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at TestNG.DuplicateExcelSheet.afterTest(DuplicateExcelSheet.java:55)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 the error is something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to copy the full excel workbook. If, so use `FileUtil` which is much more easier and lot less coding. Good thing is you do not need to worry about the destination directory, files etc. It will also overwrite if the destination exists.

```
File sourceExcel = new File("D:\\Users\\Saifur\\Desktop\\Delete\\excelFrom\\Selenium.xlsx");
File dstExcel = new File("D:\\Users\\Saifur\\Desktop\\Delete\\excelTo\\Selenium_Copy.xlsx");

try {

    FileUtils.copyFile(sourceExcel, dstExcel);

} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Make sure you have the following import

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

Maven repo [here](http://mvnrepository.com/open-source/io-utilities)

Comment: @rahulbommanaboina Glad it did. Mark the answer as accepted if this is what you have been looking for. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you declared `FileOutputStream fo` as a class member, but you are not assigning it anywhere.  So, it is **NULL** at line 55 when you try to call `fo.close()`

If `fo` is not used, I suggest you just remove it from this class.

Comment: I modified the program using fileOutputStream , still am getting the same error .. !! :(

Comment: I suggest putting all the object creation in @BeforeTest

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, you can use a debugging breakpoint and watch the state of fo change as the test executes.  [Notes on breakpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733835/how-use-break-points-in-eclipse)

Comment: ahh !! its throwing me errors if declare the objects in @ before test, as i used the objects in @Test , and coming to break points am not sure how to use them or check , as am a beginner in selenium and coding .

Comment: i got rid of exception , changed the program little bit, but now , excel sheet has been created , but data dint get copied, can some one please check the program and let me know , why the data has not been copied ??